# Using Dynamic data in a Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have a list that looks something like this :

```
listA = ["Physics","English","Chemistry","Biology","History","Human Values","None"]
```

The web page shows a textArea, where the user can add data like :-

```
Hello, My fav subject is <<English>> 
or
I like <<Biology>> , its the best
```

I want to show a validation error if the user enters anything else from what in the **listA** between the <<>>, the rest of message can be anything.

I tried using regular expression but I cant figure it out and I couldn't figure out directives. Please ask if more clarification is required

this is what I have tried so far :

```
  checkText(event) {
    // const regex = /(?:^|\s)<<(.*?)>>(?:\s|$)/g;
    var str = this.editClauseObj.textObj.text;
    console.log("str",str);

    let name_val = 'Name';
    const regex = /^([a-zA-Z]*\s)*[<<name_val>>]*\s*[a-zA-Z\s]*$/g

    if (!regex.test(str)) {
      this.showError = true;
      this.errorMessage = "Please enter a valid value inside <<>>"
      console.log("test", this.showError);

    } else {
      // do something else
      this.showError = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `[<<name_val>>]*` matches 0 or more any of these characters: `<`, `n`, `a`, `m`, `e`, `_`, `v`, `l` or `>`.

Comment: Yup, figured that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const listA = ["Physics","English","Chemistry","Biology","History","Human Values","None"];

const text = "Hello, My fav subject is <<English>> \n I like <<Biology>> , its the best \n I like <<Hello>> , its the best ";

// Look for << char and then ([^>>]+) except this >> char for 1 and more time and find the next >> char. 
const r = /<<([^>>]+)>>/g

let found=[];

while( current_found = r.exec( text ) ) {
    found.push( current_found[1] );
}

// all found items in the text
console.log(found);

// filter which is not matching 
var final = found.filter(function(item) {
  return !listA.includes(item);
});


console.log(final);
```

Comment: Had to make some modifications to it, but it worked. Thanks man